# Testing privileged app on FirefoxOS device

Tags: web-applications, firefox-os

I got stuck with the development of my web app for Firefox OS because I don't know how I can test it...
I use deviceStorage API to access sdcard, but firefoxos simulator doesn't recognize any external sdcard, so I suppose I cannot use the simulator, right?

I also have got an Unagi device (with the last firmware update), but deviceStorage API requires privileged permissions and I don't know how to test privileged apps on an actual device... If, inside the manifest, I set "type": "privileged", my app works fine with the simulator (except for the code that requires sdcard access), but if I push the app to the device, nothing works! (Javascript disabled inside the app, just HTML works)
Is there a way to test packaged PRIVILEGED apps with a firefoxos device without sending it to Firefox Marketplace? I heard that in older versions there was a "Developer mode", but it seems it has been disabled in newer version...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was under the impression that the Device Storage API worked in the simulator, it uses the folders in your operating system to save images/audio/video?

Also, pushing a privileged app to your Unagi via the Firefox OS Simulator should work, as described in https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/docs/firefox_os_simulator

Are you seeing any errors in the console that might give a clue as to what isn't working? Try typing

adb logcat

Answer (score 1):

You can make a fake sdcard on your computer:
Add a folder in the profile directory called "fake-sdcard"
 ~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxx.default/extensions/r2d2b2g@mozilla.org/profile/fake-sdcard

The simulator will look here when you call navigator.getDeviceStorage("sdcard")

I've also found that you sometimes have to restart the phone to get javascript work after you push.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is likely the [CSP (Content Security Policy)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Building_apps_for_Firefox_OS/CSP) that is applied to privileged apps.

One restriction it applies is that inline scripts inside HTML files are not allowed.  So, all scripts must be separate JS files referenced in the HTML, not inline script blocks.

The CSP only comes into effect once you add `type: privileged` to the manifest, so it's hard to notice the issue if your start without this from the beginning.  Really, there should be a warning when this happens.